# Prove that $H \cap K = H$ where $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $n, (20<n<30)$, generated by $a$ such that $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ of order $2$ and $4$ respectively. Prove that $H \cap K = H$.

What I know so far:

- The order of $G$ is divisible by $ord(H)$ and $ord(K)$, so we get that $n=24$ or $n=28$.
- $G$ is cyclic, thus $G$ is an abelian group which means that the subgroups $H$ and $G$ are normal subgroups.
- $\mid H \cap K \mid \ge 1$, since every subgroup of $G$ contains the identity element of $G$.
- $\mid H \cap K \mid \le 2$, since $\mid H \cap K \mid \le \min\{ \mid H \mid,\mid K \mid  \}$.
- Every subgroup of a cyclic group is a cyclic group, and so by using *Euler's totient function*, we get that the number of generators in $H$ and $K$ are $1$ and $2$ respectively.

I can't see how to connect all of those conclusions together, I am probably missing something basic here.

Note: 
I have not learned *Homomorphism and Isomorphism of groups* yet (in class that is).

Please refrain from giving a solution to the question but rather help me by giving me hints and criticism as it will help me improve. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given that you already know that 4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: show that a cyclic group can only have a single element (and therefore only a single subgroup) of order $2$.

More generally, for any finite, cyclic group $G$, for any order $d\mid |G|$, there is exactly one subgroup of $G$ with order $d$.

Comment: Thanks for the Hint, but if you can clear one more thing for me,
Question: if the groups were closed under multiplication modulo (let's say 4), then I would know that they definitely intersect (by finding the generators) but If I don't know that, how would I know? I'm sorry if it's a bad question.

Comment: @user412453 you can count the number of elements of any given order (that's not hard to do), and you can see how many elements you need to make a subgroup of a given order. Turns out you need all the elements that Lagrange's theorem allows you if you want to build that subgroup, so there's no room for more than one of the given order.

Comment: I know that it is something that I should have already known, but this closed a gab that I had, so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you already know that $n = 24$ or $n = 28$ you can just write down these two groups very explicitly (e.g. as integers modulo $n$) and then pick a red pen and a green pen (and if you need one a blue one as well) and  circle the elements of the potential subgroups that could play the roles of $H$ and $K$. Then check that the answer holds in all possible cases.

Now this is of course a boring answer that won't help you much solving the similar problem with $200 < n < 300$ or $2000 < n < 3000$ EXCEPT that when you actually do it you will notice something extraordinary: YOU WON'T NEED YOUR BLUE PEN. Now (of course) this doesn't come as a surprise after I just told you it will happen while moreover before that the other excellent answer by Arthur already told you the same thing.

The reason I am telling you this anyway is because of the 'deeper' lesson below it:

> Often it is good to just start to solve problems in the stupid, boring, non-informative brute-force way, as long as you keep your eyes open to anything remarkable that happens while doing it. Often these nice surprises will show you the path to a more elegant, general, desirable solution, but equally often you wouldn't have found the more desirable solution when just trying to 'come up' with it, instead of trying the boring version first.

Brian Hayes makes a similar point in a very nice way [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/27858762.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A08fe009547ce3ab8bbbe292830192c5c): of course the other children in 8-year-old Gauss's school class did not see his clever way to add the numbers 1 to 100, but had they just start doing it they would have found SOME (slightly less) clever shortcut along the way.

Comment: You are definitely right, thank you for this!